# Will I receive texts after turning send as SMS off?

Tags: iphone, sms

I want to use [Viber](http://www.viber.com/) for my calls and text messages so I turned off send as SMS. Do I still receive texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Send as SMS** only prevent sending an SMS as a fallback if iMessage fails.

You will still be able to receive and send SMS.